java.lang.Exception: net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Do not know how to convert JObject(List(JField(access_token,JString(eyJ0eXA
I tried to use lift-json dependency in one of my spark scala application and came across this issue while generating a token to access Sharepoint. This code was working with scala 2.11 and spark 2.3 and lift-Json-2.6-M4
code:
def getHttpRequest(url: String,accessToken: String): HttpEntity = {
I tired changing access_token : String to access_token : Option[String] still didn't work Can some one help on this.
Versions Im using: Scala 2.13.8
Spark 3.5.0
lift-json 3.5.0
Error Im seeing:
java.lang.Exception: net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Do not know how to convert JObject(List(JField(access_token,JString(eyJ0eXA ........) into class java.lang.String
